# No ability to upload new images via rich text editor

Tags: file-uploads

I have a strange one, or maybe it's something new to EE 3.0

I don't see an upload new file button when I click the upload file icon in a rich text field (or Expresso (plugin) field).

It brings up the list of existing files, but no button to upload a new file.

However from a custom field with a field type of 'file' it works fine?

Any ideas

thanks

Matt

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to select which directory you're trying to add it to. By default it's setting it to All.
[image]

Comment: Ah good one thanks Michael. I think that's a UX oversight on EE's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the answer, I am sorry. Where do I select that? This image is taken from Expresso Editor. Only browse files is the option, not upload new image.
[image]